# Why doesn't my applet appear in my browser?

Tags: java, html, swing, firefox, japplet

I'm pretty new to Java and completey new to applets. This is my first time trying to run an applet.  My problem is that my applet doesn't appear in the browser when I open the html file.

here's my html file:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Java Applet Demo</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <applet 
      code = "DisplayLabel.class" 
      width = "250" 
      height = "50"
      align = "center">
    </applet>
  </body>
</html>
```

and my java code

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class DisplayLabel extends JApplet {

   public DisplayLabel() {
       add(new JLabel("Great", JLabel.CENTER));
   }
}
```

i placed both files into the same path folder and tried to open the html file, but the applet doesn't appear.  When I run the applet from Eclipse or run the html from the applet viewer in the command, the applet appears.  why is this?  could it be some browser setting?

Comment: By saying you placed both files into the same folder, you do mean the .class file, and not the .java file right? Also your javapath may not be set for your browser to read, do other applets work?

Comment: does your browser have java instaled

Comment: how do i check if java is installed on my browser?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/getStarted.html

Can you see the applet on this pagE?

Comment: @Crucher This is all i see.. The HelloWorld applet shown next is a Java class that displays the string "Hello World".

Comment: @peeskillet Yeah you have java disabled/not installed

Comment: @Cruncher.. ok, thanks, I'm downloading it right now

Comment: Why code an applet?  If it is due to spec. by teacher, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should stop teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/).

Comment: @Andrew Thompson I'm actually teaching myself Programming with Java through a textbook.  Taking time off of work to learn.  Looking for a new career path.  Spending about 9 hours a day reading the chapters and doing ALL the exercises.  Would you suggest that I just skip the chapter that solely focuses on applets? Or read the chapter and skip the exercises? Or just read and do questions? I only as because each chapter will take me 4 to 7 days to complete, depending on the number of questions. And this chapter has the most exercises so far in the book.

Comment: *"Would you suggest that I just skip the chapter that solely focuses on applets?"*  If it is *all* related to applets, yes.  Applets are an insanely difficult type of program to develop, debug and deploy.  They even bring *highly experienced* Swing desktop GUI developers to tears..

Comment: Thanks, you just saved me a week of my life!